# Configuration option PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes vs PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms?

Tags: openssh

I'm using OpenSSH 8.9p1. I'm trying to connect to a git via SSH, and I'm getting

> no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa

I was able to fix the problem by adding the following to my `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host git.host.net   
    User git
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
    HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

But some places online call for using `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes`. What does this do? I don't even see documented in `man ssh`?

Comment: Do you understand why you should not add `HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa`? https://www.jhanley.com/blog/ssh-signature-algorithm-ssh-rsa-error/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the source code, the name is labeled as ["deprecated"](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/9d92e7b24848fcc605945f7c2e3460c7c31832ce/ssh.c#L803) and ["obsolete"](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/9d92e7b24848fcc605945f7c2e3460c7c31832ce/readconf.c#L323) and internally it does the same thing, [setting `sPubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/9d92e7b24848fcc605945f7c2e3460c7c31832ce/servconf.c#L579C32-L579C57).

You can [see the commit here for the intent.](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/ee9c0da8035b3168e8e57c1dedc2d1b0daf00eec)

> upstream: Rename PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes keyword to
> PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms.
>
> While the two were originally equivalent, this
> actually specifies the signature algorithms that are accepted.  Some key
> types (eg RSA) can be used by multiple algorithms (eg ssh-rsa, rsa-sha2-512)
> so the old name is becoming increasingly misleading.  The old name is
> retained as an alias.